# Facebook Graph Api OAuthException but access token is valid

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-graph-api-v2.0, facebook-permissions

I have a problem and I dont know why, I hope you could help me!

I am developing an android app which uses the facebook graph api.
It uses the readpermission "user_likes". When i do this request:
**"me/likes"** everything works fine. But when i do this:
**me/likes?fields=events{cover},name**

I get an **OAuthException**. *errorMessage: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user*

In conclusion:

1. I get a valid access token with all required permissions.
2. I am the administrator of my app so facebook privacy policy should not play any role!
3. Request

> me/likes

works, but

> me/likes?fields=events

does not work!

Response I get:

> {Response:  responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 2500, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.}, isFromCache:false}

So I debuged my Access-Token:

Issued: 1420803216 (4 hours ago)

Expires:    1425987216 (in about 2 months)

Valid:  True

Origin: Mobile Web Faceweb

Scopes: public_profile, basic_info, email, user_birthday, user_location, user_likes, user_friends

---

I do not realy understand why my access token has so many scopes? I just set "user_likes"!

```
loginBtn.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_likes"));
```

This is my Code:

```
 private LoginButton loginBtn;
    private TextView username;
    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, statusCallback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        username = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.username);
        loginBtn = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fb_login_button);
        loginBtn.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_likes"));
        loginBtn.setUserInfoChangedCallback(new UserInfoChangedCallback() {
            public void onUserInfoFetched(GraphUser user) {
                if (user != null) {
                    username.setText("You are currently logged in as "
                            + user.getName());
                } else {
                    username.setText("You are not logged in.");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {
            if (state.isOpened()) {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Facebook session opened.");
            } else if (state.isClosed()) {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Facebook session closed.");
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null && (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed())) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
        }
        uiHelper.onResume();
    }

    private void onSessionStateChange(final Session session,
            SessionState state, Exception exception) {

        if (state.isOpened()) {
            // userInfoTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            String token = session.getAccessToken();
            Log.d("SESSION_TOKEN", token);
            new Request(session, "me/likes?fields=events", null, HttpMethod.GET,
                    new Request.Callback() {
                        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                            Log.i("INFO", response.toString());
                            // new
                            // GetResponses(userInfoTextView).execute(response);
                        }
                    }).executeAsync();

        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
            // userInfoTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

What are I am doing wrong? I guess something with my session or permission request is wrong...i hope someone can help me!

kind regards
christoph

Answer (score 2):

That's because, in Facebook SDK for Android, you must pass extra parameters as a `Bundle`.

So, for your case, you should invoke the Graph object this way:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("fields", "events");

new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "me/likes", bundle, HttpMethod.GET, new GraphRequest.Callback() {
    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
        // Your stuff here
    }
}).executeAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

The API call seems to be correct and it works in the API Explorer. The only logical explanation for the error is that the Access Token is not valid.

Put the Token in the Debugger and see if it is valid and if `user_likes` is available: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: Already done... it expires in about 2 months, it is valid and all permissions are available!


Scopes public_profile, user_birthday, user_location, user_likes, user_events

Comment: then you aren´t using the access token in the call, that would be the only explanation as it works fine in the api explorer.

Comment: i tried the access-token from the android-app in the graph explorere and it worked! But when i do the same request in the android app, i always get an error. [screenshot](http://c50i.imgup.net/GraphApiCa8655.JPG?l=de)

Comment: @luschn - I faced a similar issue where I am creating a facebook pages web application using the JavaScript SDK and although I queried for a list of posts submitted by my page and had a valid page access token with the relevant permission `publish_pages`, publishing a post as a page would fail...until I actually passed in the `access_token` into the POST call `FB.api("/page_id/feed", "post", {message: message, access_token: page_access_token}, callback_handler(response){})`